# Реестр: добавление параметра

Tags: c++builder, реестр, c++

Люди, здравствуйте! Работаю на `c++ bulder` c реестром.
Вот пол интернета облазил, но кое что там догадался. 
Вот какое дело, составляю программку на `Bulder` (Да кстати хороший язык, нет ничего лишнего). Так вот, как-то поднадоела добавлять вручную свои определённые параметры после установки свежей `windows`, и решил наконец составить программку которая всё сделает за меня по составленному мной алгоритму, ну тут загвоздка, я понял как добавлять параметр `DWORD` путём небольших экспериментов, но `DWORD` у меня получается со значением либо единица либо ноль с заданием параметра либо `NULL`- ноль `false`- ноль а `true` - 1. Так вот, я хочу понять как сделать параметр в шестнадцатеричном представлении типо ( `0xFF` ) с помощью булево значения. 
А вот исходник с наработками

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry;
    reg->RootKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    reg->OpenKey("\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer",true);
    reg->WriteBool("NoDriveTypeAutoRun", "0xFF");  // Здесь хлчу добавить параметр 0xFF, а он не идёт, в реестре нуль
    reg->CloseKey();
    Application->MessageBox("Параметр добавлен", "Registry", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    delete reg;
}
```

Дополню вопрос `reg->WriteInteger("NoDriveTypeAutoRun",255 );` Так вот, нужно добавить то что я писал выше а когда пишешь числовое значение то оно в реестре FF эти 255, что нить другое пишешь вылезают совсем корявые данные. Что делать ?

Comment: писать шестнадцатеричное значение с булевый ключ, используя строку? Мисье знает толк в извращениях.

Comment: Ну как лучьше а в типах не особо, экспиреметом (учусь) методом тыка. Я вообще этот язык только начал изучать, мне он понравился из-за того что программа на нём мало весит. А на delphi весит 1 мегабайт с чем-то.

Comment: ну на самом то деле и на билдере оно много весит. И на делфи можно сделать десяток килобайт. Все выяснится, когда свой проект унесете на другой комп, где нет билдера. Раз занимаетесь самообразованием, посмотрите на [это](http://bulletinsite.net/index.php?id1=6&category=programmer&author=holingvert-dj&book=2001t1&page=140) и обратите внимание, что `WriteBool` и другие `Write*` функции имеют три параметра, а не два.

Comment: >учусь методом тыка

я надеюсь, с женщинами вы не методом тыка учитесь?

Comment: Наверное много весит потому что не relize (отладочная информация) ну сам exe мало весит , а в оперативе что-то 4400 килобайт , странновато... А на delphi exe мегабайт весит ...

Comment: Блин,разглагольствуете {Подсказали бы уже как это лучше реализуется кроме нолей и единиц.Вот это если сюда reg->WriteBool("NoDriveTypeAutoRun","0xFF");  Вместо 0xFF подставить true либо false то будет либо ноль или еденица, а как реализовать чтоб был определённый параметр типо 0xFF? 
}{ Так по по поводу этого комментария : учусь методом тыка

я надеюсь, с женщинами вы не методом тыка учитесь, а только лишь программирование таким способом осваиваете.}}}

ОТвечаю - Теория ерунда,это тебе не электричество а программирование,и тыкать можно до конца, но это может надоесть, и поэтому я пишу сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод тыка не поможет, только rtfm. Вы используете не тот метод. Вы пишете boolean, а надо Integer.

```
reg->WriteInteger("NoDriveTypeAutoRun", 255);
```

Comment: 255 в параметре 41ff  а нам нужно 0xFF , Как это узнать? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: В каком hex редакторе это определить ? Щая уточню 255 это ff , просто. А по другому как, это преобразование , я просто подзабыл.

Comment: A integer просто не пробывал (боюсь ошибки компилятора), а так спасибо за дельную подсказку, днём разберусь до конца с кодом.